# implications of past simple tense - a few minutes ago

Tags: past-tense, past-simple

I learned that the past simple tense is used for actions which are completed at a definite point in time in the past.

Then, does the sentence below imply that they are not dancing anymore now (at the moment he or she speaks)?

> A few minutes ago, they danced.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you want to say they started dancing a few minutes ago and are still dancing now, you have several options, including "They have been dancing for a few minutes."